# Double equals in for loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

Why doesn't the double equals work in a PHP for loop? The following works:

```
$cnt = 5;
for ($z = 0; $z <= $cnt; $z++) {
    echo $z."!<br />";
}
```

But why doesn't this work?

```
$cnt = 5;
for ($z = 0; $z == $cnt; $z++) {
    echo $z."!<br />";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? `0 == 5` is false, so the loop will never execute.

Comment: Ding dong. I knew I was overlooking something really simple. Thank you.

Comment: What I was looking for was: 

$cnt = 5;
for ($z = 0; $z != $cnt; $z++) {
    echo $z."!<br />";
}

Comment: If you simply use `$z != $cnt` without making any other changes, then the loop will iterate one less time than the original loop.

Answer (score 3):

The loop executes only if the condition evaluates to `true`. At the first iteration, `$z == $cnt` is `false`, so the loop never executes.

A common loop strategy is to use a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value):

```
$cnt = 5;
$stop = $cnt + 1;
for ($z = 0; $z != $stop; $z++) {
    . . .
}
```

Note that the comparison is negative (`!=` or `!==`). Using a sentinel is usually unnecessary for numerical loop variables (I wouldn't recommend it for your posted code), but is useful for other situations (e.g., when `$stop` represents `null`, an illegal value, etc.). It's particularly helpful when the loop variable changes in a pattern that is not easy to characterize succinctly.

Answer (score 1):

because on the first iteration `$z != $cnt`, so the loop stops immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `for` is:

```
for (<init>; <condition>; <increment>)
```

The loop tests `<condition>` before each iteration. If it's `true`, it executes that iteration; if it's `false`, the loop terminates.

In your case, since `$z == $cnt` is `false` before the first iteration, the loop terminates immediately.

To do what you want, invert the test. You also need to bump the end value up by one, since the original version used `<=`, not `<`. Note that in both cases, the loop executes `$cnt+1` times, because you start from 0.

```
for ($z = 0; $z != $cnt+1; $z++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us look at this from the computer's perspective:

If I am a computer this is what you told me to do:

- set               $cnt = 5;
- set               $z = 0;
- check if          $z equals $cnt
- if so             do whatever is in the loop, then increment $z

Trouble is, 5 does not equal 0 and never will, so the loop will simply be skipped. If you had $cnt = $z+1 inside the loop this would be an infinite loop.

So, you see, == works just fine, it simply doesn't do what you think it should do.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

A for loop works by looping until a condition is made false.  In the first example the loop will execute until z = 5 after that z will not longer be less than or equal to cnt (z starts at 0 and increments through each loop).  In the second example you have $z == $cnt as your condition, and since z = 0 and cnt = 5 the loop will stop automatically because the condition is made false.  You can use not equals instead like following:

```
$cnt = 6;
for ($z = 0; $z != $cnt; $z++) {
    echo $z."!<br />";
}
```